# What is the algorithm solve this in FPDF?

Tags: php, algorithm, fpdf

I am going to generate report by using [FPDF](http://fpdf.org/).

My Problem Like this the horizontal data is too long to display in A4 or A3 :

```
V  ->  H1 ->   H2 ->    H3............>    HTotal
v1 ->   1       2       3   ..........>    1+2+3+..n
v2 ->   1       2       3    .........>    1+2+3+..n
v3 ->   1       2       3    .........>    1+2+3+..n
.......................................
Vtotal  1*n     2*n     3*n...........>    (1+2+3+..n)*n
```

Example

```
V  ->  H1  ->  H2->  H3 -> H4 ->   TOTAL
v1    1       2      3     4        10
v2    1       2      3     4        10
v3    1       2      3     4        10
v4    1       2      3     4        10 
VT   4        8      12    16      40
```

so my PDF can be output like (split the display pages)

```
V  ->  H1 ->  H2
v1    1        2  
v2    1        2   
v3    1        2    
v4    1        2  
VT    4        8   

V  -> H3->H4 
v1    3     4  
v2    3     4 
v3    3     4    
v4    3     4   
VT   12    16 

V  ->  TOTAL
v1     10
v2     10
v3     10
v4     10 
VT     40
```

so even if the data it too long I still got the data display.

Could anyone help me:

- solve this problem ?

  - or suggest to me the solution using FPDF?
  - or suggest an algorithm in PHP?

Comment: You could create the table using multi cells. But you would need to do some calculations before plotting the table. Usually we work with the height to see if it will fall onto a new page. But with your table you will have to be calculating the width (assuming the table height always fits the page). If you fix the col width it would be simpler to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of Course that you cant put 100 columns at a A4, but to by more space, you may like to write columns vertically, (just column headers), as i see data that you are putting at your columns are numbers, so the only issue is header of it, like TOTAL, you may write it vertically like:
T
O
T
A
L